# Deriving Demand for Exponent Term for Quasilinear Utilities

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility

Consider a quasilinear utility function:  $u(x, y) = x+4 y^{.5} \quad \text{s.t.} \, I=P_{x}x+P_{y}y$. I know how to calculate the demand for good $x$, beginning with
\begin{align*}
&\cfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x + 4 y^{.5}\right)=1 &  \cfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(x + 4 y^{.5}\right)=\cfrac{2}{y^{.5}}
\end{align*}
and substituting the solution for $y$ into our budget constraint
\begin{align*}
\cfrac{\cfrac{2}{y^{.5}}}{1}=\cfrac{P_y}{P_x} \Rightarrow y=\cfrac{4P_{x}^2}{P_{y}^2} \Rightarrow I=P_{x}x+P_{y}\cfrac{4P_{x}^2}{P_{y}^2}.
\end{align*}
Marshallian demand for $x$ works out to
\begin{align*}
&x_{M}=\frac{IP_{y}-4P_{x}^2}{P_{x}P_{y}}.
\end{align*}
But, what about the demand function for good $y$? No econ book that I have (Varian's Microecon, and others) really gives a straightforward answer (that I've yet found) for the full demand system. What would the first steps be for deriving demand for good $y$?

Comment: This might help: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/51756/11824

Comment: You can use the budget constraint and the demand for $X$ ($x^d$)to determine the demand for $Y$ in this case. $y^d= \dfrac{I-p_Xx^d}{p_Y}$

Comment: @ Jared Greathouse. Be careful when you take a derivative, the derivative with respect to $y$ is not correct, it is $20y^4$.

Comment: @BakerStreet Incorrect. $y^.5 = y^{1/2}$. By the power rule, this is $0.5y^{-.5}$, and when we rearrange the negative exponent, we get what I got. It would be $20y^4$ if the exponent was 5, though.

Comment: Why $y^5= y^{1/2}$?? In your text, in the utility function, there is $y^5$, the exponent is $5$.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo, in the utility function the exponent should be $0.5$, not $5$

Comment: No, in the original utility function, it's $.5$. Unless someone edited it after I wrote it. But, you're right, I should've been clearer and put $0.5$.

Comment: Ah, there is point before $5$, this is the reason.  But honestly it is impossible to see it without a microscope :-). It is not your fault, it is the lateX here that makes the point very small.