# How to derive the indirect utility function of $u(x_1,x_2) = x_2+ 2\sqrt{x_1}$?

Tags: microeconomics, utility

I derived the utility $u(x_1,x_2) = x_2 + 2\sqrt{x_1}$ from the indirect utility $V(x_1,x_2) = \frac{y}{p_2} + \frac{p_2}{p_1}$ but cannot go the other direction without finding very complicated solutions for the explicit solution of the Marshallian demands.

Comment: It is quite straightforward here to find the Marshallian demands. Can you show your working? Then we could tell you were you are going wrong.

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/16475/11824